# The command "git rm -r <directory name>" isn't working?

Tags: github, directory, duplicates

When I hit enter, it tells me "fatal: pathspec 'Directory Name' did not match any files". but the ls command brings up all the directories and it's there. Is there a special command I need to enter to get rid of a directory specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Check first your `git status` and `git check-ignore -v -- <directory name>/afile` to see if `<directory name>` is tracked.

If it is not tracked, then a simple `rm` (no `git`) would be enough.